# Let $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ with $n \geq 2$ and let $a\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

(a) Prove that $[a]_n$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ (i.e. $[a]_n$ has a multiplcative inverse) if and only if $\mathrm{gcd}(a,n)=1$

(b) Prove that $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a field if and only if $n$ is prime.

Any advice prove this please!

Comment: Could use a much better title.

Comment: @Ihf :) like what??

Comment: @Wes (b) has been answered at least twice elsewhere on the site. Try searching for it.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

For a), Use the fact that $\mathrm{gcd}(a, n) = 1$ to write down $1$ as some linear combination of $a$ and $n$.

For b), use a): what is true of every prime number?

Comment: a prime number has divisors 1 and itself?

Comment: Right - so what is true of the gcd of a prime $p$ and any integer less than $p$? :)

Comment: $p$ is prime and $q$ is an integer, less than $p$, then $gcd(p,q)=1$?

Comment: That's right. Think about it. If some integer $k$ divides $p$, then it has to be $1$, or $p$. If $k | q$, and $q < p$, since $k \leq q$, then it follows that $k < p$, so $k$ must be $1$.

Comment: Thanks! I will think about it.